# Sync custom folder icon with Dropbox

Tags: finder, folders, dropbox

I have added custom folder icons to some of the folders in my Dropbox. I would like this to get synced across devices, but it seems that it does not. Is there a way to get custom icons to sync with Dropbox?

On Windows XP (if mind serves me right) I think I could use desktop.ini files in a folder to set some preferences. Perhaps there is something similar for Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your icon files are stored in the `.DS_Store` file located in each folder.  This file is what contains the metadata of the folder including the custom icon, the icon spacing, etc.

[What is a .DS_Store file?](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/31/what-is-a-ds_store-file/)

Drop Box, does not sync this particular file.  According to their [help guide](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/145) `.DS_Store` is ignored:

[image]

This means that your custom icon won't get synced.  You will have to create the custom icon manually.

Comment: Great explanation, but still a bit sad. I guess they do it to avoid users having lots of hidden duplicate files.